# What are the performance implications, if any, of chaining too many `.then`s on Promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, reduce

I have an implementation of **reduce** that could potentially chain many `.then` handlers together.

```
const reduceIterable = (fn, x0, x) => {
  const iter = x[Symbol.iterator].call(x)
  let cursor = iter.next()
  if (cursor.done) {
    throw new TypeError('reduce(...)(x); x cannot be empty')
  }
  let y = !isUndefined(x0) ? fn(x0, cursor.value) : (() => {
    const x0 = cursor.value
    cursor = iter.next()
    return cursor.done ? x0 : fn(x0, cursor.value)
  })()
  cursor = iter.next()
  while (!cursor.done) {
    const { value } = cursor
    y = isPromise(y) ? y.then(res => fn(res, value)) : fn(y, value)
    cursor = iter.next()
  }
  return y
}

// you would use reduce like reduce(add, 0)([1, 2, 3]) // => 6
const reduce = (fn, x0) => {
  if (!isFunction(fn)) {
    throw new TypeError('reduce(x, y); x is not a function')
  }
  return x => {
    if (isIterable(x)) return reduceIterable(fn, x0, x)
    if (isAsyncIterable(x)) return reduceAsyncIterable(fn, x0, x)
    if (is(Object)(x)) return reduceObject(fn, x0, x)
    throw new TypeError('reduce(...)(x); x invalid')
  }
}
```

Specifically, I'm looking at `y.then(res => fn(res, value))` because of this [issue](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/179). I know Promises have come a long way since then, but this has never been resolved. I really want to know if I'm okay to consume the Promise API like this, or if I need to do something harder.

Comment: Honestly, micro-optimizations aren't worth it. It may leak some memory, but it won't cause too much of a performance impact in the long run. If you *really* wanted maximum performance, you could use a Promise library like Bluebird. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278778/why-are-native-es6-promises-slower-and-more-memory-intensive-than-bluebird

Comment: Is this for backwards-compatibility with JavaScript environments that don’t support async functions? Async functions solve the problem of creating too more promises than necessary nicely.

Comment: @Ry- aren't async functions just syntactic sugar for promises in the end? i.e. same number of promises and same performance?

Comment: @Ry- this is for a feature of `reduce` where you can put a completely sync function in it and have the evaluation be sync, but also be able to put an async function in it and have it return a promise

Comment: @101arrowz: Same capabilities, but not same performance in general. They’re often implemented like generators. (Also, the equivalent with promises looks different from the implementation here anyway.)

Comment: @richytong: So it would be acceptable to use an async function?

Comment: @Ry- yes, or a chain of async functions expressed by `pipe`

Comment: [async/await under the hood](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async#await-under-the-hood)

Comment: FWIW I don’t think writing very overloaded functions like this `reduce` is a good idea.

Comment: @Ry- actually I may have misinterpreted your comment just now. Why do you think it's not a good idea to overload `reduce`?

Comment: @richytong: When calling a function, the types involved are usually known by the caller. Having a function with multiple different paths that can be taken at runtime be the default increases complexity and can hide bugs. For example, if you expect to use this on an iterable and accidentally pass the wrong value but the wrong value is an object, instead of getting an error, you get a variable wrong behaviour. It also interferes with composability: if you want to write a generic function for iterables that doesn’t special-case promises, you can’t make use of this `reduce`.

Comment: @Ry- would it be better to split this reduce function up by type?

Comment: @richytong: I think so, yeah.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215051/discussion-between-richytong-and-ry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the performance implications, if any, of chaining too many `.then`s on Promises?

If you compare a `.reduce()` loop where you chain lots of `.then()` onto each other in order to sequence asynchronous operation and compare that to an `await` loop inside an async function where you finish one operation before starting the next, the main difference will be in peak memory usage.  Chaining a lot of `.then()` together will have the full chain of all the promise objects in memory at once.  If you do an `await` loop, you only have one promise active at a time.

Now, promises are not large objects so even if your chain is thousands of elements long, it probably still may not be a material difference.  But, if you want to minimize peak memory usage, an `await` loop would keep the peak memory usage lower.

As for pure execution speed, the story is the same as always.  If you really cared about execution speed, you'd have to write a representative test program using the `.reduce()` loop and a program that generated equivalent output and sequencing using an `await` loop and benchmark the two.  Performance is so dependent upon speicific circumstances that you have to measure if you really want to know which is faster.  Theorizing is often wrong because our intuition doesn't always know what the real bottleneck is.  You have to measure.

FYI, `async/await` have been sped up quite a bit in the last few nodejs releases.

Answer (score 1):

Creating as many promises as iterable elements, all at once, probably isn’t good for a generic function. It breaks down completely for infinite iterables.

You could break out to an async function on detecting a promise:

```js
const reduceAwait = async (fn, initial, iterable) => {
  let m = await initial

  for (const n of iterable) {
    m = await fn(m, n)
  }

  return m
}

const reduceIterable = (fn, initial, iterable) => {
  const iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]()
  let m = initial

  if (initial === undefined) {
    const first = iter.next()

    if (first.done) {
      throw new TypeError('reduce of empty iterable with no initial value')
    }

    m = first.value
  }

  for (const n of iterator) {
    m = fn(m, n)

    if (isPromise(m)) {
      return reduceAwait(fn, m, iterator)
    }
  }

  return m
}
```

`m = await fn(m, n)` can also become

```js
m = fn(m, n)

if (isPromise(m)) {
  m = await m
}
```

if you want minimal microtasks for mixed inputs.